# How to initialize fields of class with data from file

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, initialization

I want initialize properties of my class with some data from file. I created DataSourceAttribute for classes and DataItemAttribute for properties. I also created abstract parent class for these classes for which I want initialize fields. See code below:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class DataInitializerAttribute: Attribute
{}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DataItemAttribute: Attribute
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return "someValue"; // here I will read file}
    }

    public DataItemAttribute(string fileName)
    {            
        FileName = fileName;
    }       
}

public abstract class PropertyInitializer
{
    protected PropertyInitializer()
    {
        var classAttribute = GetType().GetCustomAttribute<DataInitializerAttribute>();
        if (classAttribute == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var properties = GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var attribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<DataItemAttribute>();
            if (attribute == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            property.SetValue(this, attribute.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works good, but maybe it is possible to implement more elegant solution without inheriting of PropertyInitializer class?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here exactly, but have you considered an IoC framework (like Spring.NET) that allows you to create beans of your object and its properties?

Comment: You could serialize / deserialize from a xml file to save/load your class.

Comment: I want to implement custom solution for initialization of fields of some class. I want to support different data sources: text file, xml, excel... As I see it  - I will mark my field with attribute [DataItem(DataSource = "Excel", file="1.xlsx", filed="SomeFiled")]. It's just example. And I am searching for solution where I should not inherit all my classes from PropertyInitializer class.

Comment: This sounds like a post that should be migrated to CodeReview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.